# Instalação owncloud - Não faz login inicial

Tags: instalador, configuração, cloud

Para instalar o OwnCloud adotei os seguintes procedimentos:

a) Download do OwnCloud Community
b) Descompactação
c) Envio para o servidor onde está o hosting
d) Informações iniciais de configuração:

1. administrador do owncloud
2. senha do administrador
3. Banco de dados: mysql
4. User do Mysql, database name, database hostname, hostname address:3306 (porta Mysql)

e) Fui tentar acessar como o user e senha do administrador

Não houve nenhuma resposta. Não sai da tela de login.

Quem pode me dizer que erro pode estar impedindo o login inicial?